# How to deploy nodejs and express to AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, mean-stack, backend

I have a MEAN application that needs deployment and I chose to deploy it on AWS Linux AMI but I have some problems deploying it.

Based on the tutorials I read so far every nodejs and express contains html pages.

How do I deploy it without html pages on it? like if they go to the domain they just see a blank page?

I know I can just empty an html file but I any other solutions?

here's my server.js

```
const http = require("http");
const debug = require("debug")("sales-and-inventory");
const app = require("./app");

// normalizePort() makes sure that the port is a valid number data type
const normalizePort = val => {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);
  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // isNot-a-Number
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
};

// checks the type of error occured
const onError = error => {
  if (error.syscall !== "listen") {
    throw error;
  }

  const bind = typeof port === "string" ? "pipe " + port : "port " + port;
  switch (error.code) {
    case "EACCES":
      console.error(bind + " requires elevated privileges");
      process.exit(1);
      break;

      case "EADDRINUSE":
      console.error(bind + " is already in use");
      process.exit(1);
      break;

    default:
      throw error;
  }
};

// just logging
const onListening = () => {
  const addr = server.address();
  const bind = typeof port === "string" ? "pipe " + port : "port " + port;
  debug("Listening on " + bind);
};

// set a config for the express environment & config for the port
const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || "3000");
app.set("port", port);

const server = http.createServer(app);

// registered on this listeners on the function above
server.on("error", onError);
server.on("listening", onListening);

// start server
server.listen(port);
```

here's the app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const authRoutes = require("../routes/auth.route");
const userRoutes = require("../routes/user.route");
const customerRoutes = require("../routes/customer.route");
const vendorRoutes = require("../routes/vendor.route");
const salesRoutes = require("../routes/sales-order.route");
const purchaseRoutes = require("../routes/purchase-order.route");
const inventoryRoutes = require("../routes/inventory.route");
const transferRoutes = require("../routes/transfer.route");
const paymentRoutes = require("../routes/payment.route");


const app = express();

mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.connect(process.env.ATLAS_CONNECTION_STRING, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Connected to Atlas");
    })
    .catch(err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {

    // allows any domain to access our resources
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    // allows domain with a certain set of headers
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    );

    // allows http type of requests
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    );

    res.header('Content-Security-Policy', 'img-src "self"');
    next();
});




app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/customer", customerRoutes);
app.use("/api/vendor", vendorRoutes);
app.use("/api/sales", salesRoutes);
app.use("/api/purchase", purchaseRoutes);
app.use("/api/inventory", inventoryRoutes);
app.use("/api/transfer", transferRoutes);
app.use("/api/payment", paymentRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

After launching the EC2 Instance, you can go ahead with the setting SSH on your machine if you are using windows go for PUTTY.

Follow this tutorial for deploying NodeJS Application once you are logged into instance.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tasoWTGM1hA

Answer (score -2):

before deploying Make sure add Security group to EC2 instance and add the role of HTTP, HTTPS with any IP address I mean 0.0.0.0 and any port :0

Comment: unrelated to my question.